# jquery & dojo not loading after HTML 5 offline caching

Tags: jquery, html, dojo, offline-caching, offline-browsing

I have an html site 
head section of that html site

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script> 
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script> 
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/basic.js'></script> 
 <script src="js/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

The manifesto file

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#version 1.0
index.html
```

Do i need to add each of the dojo files to manifesto or simply index.html will take Right now im getting the error after allowing the browser for local storage is "dojo is not defined" & "$(document).ready"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single file must be added to the manifest as steted [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#appcache).
The exception is index.html which is added automatically.
Also, you can specifify a NETWORK section in which to put external documents / data sources / links that have to be accessed from inside your application. Note that the cache.manifest will bleck your external request if they are not included in the network section.